# Help setting up anonymous proxy!

Tags: proxy, ip, squid

So I have a VPS with like 20 different IP addresses. I've installed squid3 and it's working. The problem is that when I search online "what's my ip" the IP that appears is the VPS ip. What I want to accomplish is that every time I send a request to the server it switches the network interface so if I do that exact same search query it displays a different IP every time.

I don't know if that's even possible. So, can anybody help me. The OS is Ubuntu 14.04 btw.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, you'll have to split the load for the 20 outgoing IPs.

Information can be found here. [Link](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/AclRandom)

In your squid configuration, something like this should work...

```
acl r_20 random 1/20
acl r_19 random 1/19
acl r_18 random 1/18
acl r_17 random 1/17
acl r_16 random 1/16
acl r_15 random 1/15
acl r_14 random 1/14
acl r_13 random 1/13
acl r_12 random 1/12
acl r_11 random 1/11
acl r_10 random 1/10
acl r_9 random 1/9
acl r_8 random 1/8
acl r_7 random 1/7
acl r_6 random 1/6
acl r_5 random 1/5
acl r_4 random 1/4
acl r_3 random 1/3
acl r_2 random 1/2
acl r_1 random 1/1

tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.20 r_20
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.19 r_19
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.18 r_18
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.17 r_17
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.16 r_16
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.15 r_15
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.14 r_14
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.13 r_13
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.12 r_12
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.11 r_11
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.10 r_10
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.9 r_9
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.8 r_8
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.7 r_7
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.6 r_6
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.5 r_5
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.4 r_4
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.3 r_3
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.2 r_2
tcp_outgoing_address x.x.0.1 r_1
```

Comment: I'm assuming "r_1" to "r_20" are the network interfaces?

Comment: And x.x.0.1 the IP of each interface right?

Comment: So...what's the meaning of the fractions "1/1","1/2"...etc?

Comment: r_1 can be anything you want to name it, it's symbolic.  The IP will have to be allocated and assigned to an interface.  The x.x.x.x will be the assignment.

Comment: It's the division of weights per acl, essentially 5% each.  I believe squid will use random() but I don't know how it allocates each time, so it may not seem all that random.  An external acl might be better if you find the internal option sufficient.